# trigger in MySQL to disallow multiple row deletions at a time on a table

Tags: mysql, trigger

How do we create a trigger in MySql to disallow deletion of more than 2 rows from (say) `employee` table by a single query?

```
delimiter \\
create trigger not_more_than_2_rows  
before delete on  employee
begin
declare count int default 0;   
if (count>1) then  
    signal sqlstate '12345'
    set message_text = 'cannot delete more than 2 rows at a time'
end if;
set count = count+1
end \\
delimiter ;
```

but this does not seem to work, the `count` variable is getting initialized for each row.
I could see that one way to overcome this is to initialize variable `count` once per trigger execution instead of once for each row....

Any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

This goes against all that righteous and good in triggers but here we go...

Create a table that keep a count of attempted deletes per connection

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trigger_happy_employee_deletes
(
    delete_count INT DEFAULT 0,
    conn_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (connection_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

or to reduce disk I/O make it a MEMORY table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trigger_happy_employee_deletes
(
    delete_count INT DEFAULT 0,
    conn_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (connection_id)
) ENGINE=MEMORY;
```

Now get the count from that table and check it

```
delimiter \\
create trigger not_more_than_2_rows  
before delete on  employee
begin
declare count int;
insert ignore into trigger_happy_employee_deletes (conn_id) values (connection_id());
select delete_count into count
    from trigger_happy_employee_deletes
    where conn_id = connection_id()
;
set count = count + 1;
update trigger_happy_employee_deletes
    set delete_count = count
    where conn_id = connection_id()
;
if (count>1) then  
    signal sqlstate '12345'
    set message_text = 'cannot delete more than 2 rows at a time'
end if;
end \\
delimiter ;
```

After your issue a DELETE command, you will have to remember to clear the count like this:

```
delete from employee where ... ;
update trigger_happy_employee_deletes
    set delete_count = 0
    where conn_id = connection_id()
;
```

or you count clear it before:

```
update trigger_happy_employee_deletes
    set delete_count = 0
    where conn_id = connection_id()
;
delete from employee where ... ;
```

Give it a Try !!!

## POTENTIAL DRAWBACKS

Here are the pitfalls of doing this:

#### Pitfall #1

Using an arbitration method like this (via a MyISAM table) will cause a major bottleneck because a `MyISAM` performs a full table lock on each `INSERT`. Using a MEMORY table will not fare much better because although there is far less table access on disk, there is still nominal disk I/O hitting the MEMORY table's `.frm` file that can cause a slight bottleneck when given enough database traffic.

You cannot make `trigger_happy_employee_deletes` InnoDB because triggers do not work intelligently with InnoDB:

- `Jun 21, 2011` : [Using MySQL triggers or transactions?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3397/using-mysql-triggers-or-transactions/3409#3409)
- `Mar 21, 2011` : [Dynamic SQL in MySQL stored routines](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/321/dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-routines/1906#1906)

#### Pitfall #2

From a coding perspective, you will have to remember to setup this mechanism across your code. If you forget to do this in all necessary places, you will have undesired deletions.

#### Pitfall #3

If you want this same mechanism for another table, you would either make another `trigger_happy` table for deletes or be tempted to merge all delete triggers into a common `trigger_happy` table, which would make maintenance a total nightmare, not to mention increased bottlenecks by an order of magnitude. Even worse, you may be tempted to merge update and insert triggers into the common `trigger_happy` table.

#### Pitfall #4

The trigger would have to communicate with another table outside the triggered table. That's more internal read traffic just to maintain a count.

Comment: haha, I +1'd for "This goes against all that righteous and good in triggers", but then -1'd for showing how, so we're at a net no-gain currently!

Comment: @DTest haha That's why I said "but here it goes"

Comment: I'll remove my virtual downvote for a +1 gain if you expand on what potential issues doing this could cause.

Comment: Yeh, I answered one like this once.  I told the guy not to do it, showed him how, explained why not to do it, and gave some alternatives.  I still lost about 10 reputation.  I'm going to upvote this because you told him what he asked, AND told him not to do it.

Comment: @mdoyle what that question in DBA.SE or another site ???

Comment: I don't recall.  I think it was elsewhere.

Comment: @mdoyle I think I found it. Was it this one ??? : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10234656/491757

Comment: Hahaha, yep, that was the one! :)

Comment: @mdoyle I guess some don't like being told their choice could be done better, especially when you show them. I read it through. I'll give it +1 because one can still learn from it anyway.

Comment: Well, thanks!  To be fair, I don't think it was the OP that downvoted it; the downvotes showed up with the cautionary comments.

Comment: @rolando Thnx for the detailed reply rolando. Keeping aside performance issues..   Iam concerned about having to remember to reset the field 'delete_count' to 0 each time before or after a 'delete' query. Can we avoid this ??    Do we have a function to get a new id for each query instead of each connection