# Get a user's rank from an equation, and then store it in the table

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a project for my database class, and I have a table called "accounts". It looks like [image: this]

What I want to do is have a stored procedure where it calculates the new ranks for each account. The ranks will be based off a value (higher the better) that will be computed with an equation I am working on. How would I be able to get the rank, and store the rank in my table?

Ex: Account_id||Games_won||Games_lost||(calculated value) *not in table*||Account_rank

```
         1        200           157              1856                    1
```

**EDIT: Here is my CREATE TABLE statement:**

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS league_of_legends.accounts (

`account_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

`account_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,

`account_password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,

`subscriber_first_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,

`subscriber_last_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,

`subscriber_email_address` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,

`subscriber_dob` DATE NOT NULL,

`server` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,

`account_balance` INT NULL,

`games_won` INT NULL,

`games_lost` INT NULL,

`account_rank` INT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (`account_id`, `account_name`, `subscriber_email_address`));

**My INSERT sample statements:**
INSERT INTO accounts (account_id, account_name, account_password, subscriber_first_name, subscriber_last_name, subscriber_email_address, subscriber_dob, server, account_balance, **games_won**, **games_lost**, **account_rank**)

VALUES (DEFAULT, 'Bwomp', 'asdfqwer', 'Nile', 'Williams', 'getrekt@gmail.com', '2003-10-09', 'NA', 1250, **100**, **100**, **NULL**),

(DEFAULT, 'Dirty Dan', '1234567890', 'Daniel', 'Brown', 'awovuca-1084@yopmail.com', '1990-07-16', 'EU', 0, **3**, **20**, **NULL**),

(DEFAULT, 'Alfy', 'doodcool', 'Alfonso', 'Riggleman', 'AlfonsoRRiggleman@armyspy.com', '1992-12-27', 'KR', 50, **400**, **410**, **NULL**),

(DEFAULT, 'Justaguy1', 'retrodonkey', 'Nick', 'Chetta', 'NicholasSMaine@jourrapide.com', '1996-06-28', 'NA', 3, **0**, **5**, **NULL**);

**Sample equation:**

(Games_won / total_games) * games_won = value

Comment: Please post a SHOW CREATE TABLE accounts\G. Also, please give us some sample DDL (INSERT INTO accounts VALUES(....)) and your desired result and the logic you used to get it. Also, need a sample ranking equation - 1856/43 = 43.16... how is it calculated?

Comment: ok, let me edit it.

Comment: Need the equation if you could post that also.

Comment: Just posted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - this should be easy for the first part, if you're willing to be a bit adventurous :-).

MariaDB has had [computed columns](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/virtual-computed-columns/) (otherwise known as virtual or generated columns) for quite a while now. Otherwise, the latest milestone release of MySQL (5.7.7) also [has them](https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/04/29/generated-virtual-columns-in-mysql-5-7-labs/).

If you want to do this with a current GA version, you'll have to use TRIGGERs.

However, if you want to update the RANK (see a lovely post [here](http://fellowtuts.com/mysql/query-to-obtain-rank-function-in-mysql/)) on each update of games_won/games_lost, then you'll have to call a PROCEDURE which will update RANK. MySQL's Stored Procedure programming language isn't sophisticated enough for this on its own, but see [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10657/call-a-stored-procedure-from-a-trigger) for some ideas. It says that there can be rollback issues, but since you're updating only one table, it should be easier than most - good luck :-). BTW, I'd use float/double for games_won/_lost - otherwise, you might have problems with integer division.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I'm going to try experimenting with this, and hopefully I get it to work properly. =)

Answer (score -1):

My $0.02; perform the calculation app side. It will scale better. Its possible to perform the calculation in an `update` or an `insert on duplicate key update` statement.