# How can I pass object to procedure from trigger?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, trigger

I am using mysql 5.6.
After insert or update, inside the trigger I am calling procedure, So how can i  pass NEW and OLD object from trigger to procedure ?

Answer (score 2):

I found this: [**SOURCE**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10657/call-a-stored-procedure-from-a-trigger)

> There is great reason why you should never call stored procedures from
>   within triggers.
>
> Triggers are, by nature, stored procedures. Their actions are virtually hard to roll back. Even if all underlying tables are InnoDB,
>   you will experience a proportional volume of shared row locks and
>   annoying intermittency from exclusive row locks. Such would be the
>   case if triggers were manipulating tables with INSERTs and UPDATEs
>   being stagnated to perform heavy duty MVCC inside each call to a
>   trigger.
>
> Don't forget that Triggers require overhead. In fact, According to MySQL Stored Procedure Programming, page 256 under the head "Trigger
>   Overhead" says the following:
>
> It is important to remember that, by necessity, triggers add overhead
>   to the DML statement to which they apply. the actual amount of
>   overhead will depend upon the nature of the trigger, but --- as all
>   MySQL triggers execute FOR EACH ROW --- the overhead can rapidly
>   accumulate for statements that process large numbers of rows. You
>   should therefore avoid placing any expensive SQL statements or
>   procedural code in triggers. An expanded explanation of trigger
>   overhead is given on pages 529-531. The concluding point from that
>   section states the following:
>
> The lesson here is this: since the trigger code will execute once for
>   every row affected by a DML statement, the trigger can easily become
>   the most significant factor in DML performance. Code inside the
>   trigger body needs to be as lightweight as possible and -- in
>   particular -- any SQL statements in the trigger should be supported by
>   indexes whenever possible.

Check [**RolandoMySQLDBA**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/877/rolandomysqldba) answer.