# MySQL trigger to update a key if record exists

Tags: mysql, trigger, mariadb

I'm trying to build a trigger in MariaDB to follow this logic:

```
1. If the primary key val exists, increment the counter column
2. Else, insert the primary key into the table
```

Here is my prosed trigger:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER volume_manager BEFORE INSERT ON individual_key_log
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.reference_key not in (
            select *
            From individual_key_log
            where (NEW.reference_key = 'test')
        ) THEN -- MISSING THEN
           CALL `Insert not allowed`;
        END IF;
    END;
//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: What columns does the table have? The output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE individual_key_log;` would help. Which is the "counter" column? Do you want to insert or not if the key does not exist in the table? (that "insert not allowed" is confusing)

Comment: Show us the desired SQL without using a `TRIGGER`.

Answer (score 1):

Why write a trigger for this ? I have two reasons why you should not do that in this instance.

## REASON #1

Let's assume the following:

- `reference_key`

  - is not an auto_increment column
  - is the primary key
- `counter`

  - is the column to increment
  - is defined as `INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1`

You can write the INSERT as follows

```
INSERT INTO individual_key_log (reference_key,...)
VALUES (...) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE counter = counter + 1;
```

This is a much cleaner approach than a trigger

## REASON #2

I noticed you have a CALL in the middle of your trigger. Believe me, you do not want to make a trigger that breaks midstream unless it is necessary. Calling anything in a trigger requires overhead and can hamper query performance. I wrote about this back on `Jan 13, 2012` : [Call a stored procedure from a trigger](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10657/call-a-stored-procedure-from-a-trigger/10663#10663)

I also wrote about how jerryrigging a trigger can halt normal operation if not done properly : See my post from `Apr 25, 2011` : [Trigger in MySQL to prevent insertion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2368/trigger-in-mysql-to-prevent-insertion/2371#2371) where I demonstrate how to halt a trigger to prevent insertion checking a separate table.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `iNSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` semantic:

```
INSERT INTO individual_key_log (reference_key,...) 
       VALUES (...)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE counter=counter+1;
```